# Download button - icon representing the action or subject

Tags: buttons, download, pdf

When adding an icon to a button labelled 'Download free ebook' one can use an icon to represent either the action (download) or the subject matter (PDF). Which is better? Why? (And is the answer impacted by context or intended user?)

Comment: Icons are used to imply both action and label and more. Here is an example of all the ways icons are used > https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/   Could you highlight what exactly you are looking for? Any specific design decision you need to take around this?

Comment: Not trying to be harsh, but StackExchange isn't meant to ask for opinions. You can ask these type of questions on forums. StackExchange is meant to answer questions that aren't opinion-based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine you have designed a music player and the play button icon represented the format of the song that will play when you click it, i.e. instead of the "play arrow" it had an icon representing the "mp3" format of the file. Would that make sense?

If a button triggers an action then it usually makes much more sense to have the icon reflect the action. The information about the item being acted upon can be indicated elsewhere (in the music player example it would be in the playlist, or a "currently playing" display of some sort).

Comment: While I agree with your answer I'd say it's not true in this case. Your example 'Play' is about something that the user simply doesn't care about. The user just wants to press the button and have music, which will happen. But with downloading the user wants to download it and see if it is of any use for him/her. It could be any file (maybe a file he can't open). So I think the 'Download' button should contain the text "Download" and an icon of the document type, which is PDF in this case.

Comment: @DaanHeskes It is much better to have a big green download arrow as an icon, and then "filename.pdf" (or even just "PDF"). A user is on the page looking for a download, they are going to scan (users don't read, they scan) for any download buttons before narrowing down to possible formats.

Comment: Seems arguably, which is probably why they're both used. When your button calls to action I think they will see "Download" and the PDF icon, which is a better experience for the user than only having a "Download" button with an arrow icon. Some people might want to make sure they're about to download a PDF document when downloading an ebook. So for the user experience I'd say it's better to show the document type in OP's case. But the right answer seems kinda opinion-wise.

Comment: @DaanHeskes If you think that I suggested *not* having information displayed about the file format you should go back and read what I actually wrote.

Comment: I didn't say that you don't have that suggested, but I'm saying that your answer is about something that you can't compare. A music play/stop button is totally different than a download button. For me a 'Download PDF' with a PDF file is way clearer than a "Download", "filename.pdf" and the big green arrow icon. I'm talking about a button [like this](http://puu.sh/mry8M/43dd72f925.png).

Comment: What if there were 3 download buttons, each one a different file format. Maybe an icon indicating the format instead of the action would be more useful.. While I like your music player analogy, I think it can be a little too simplified to apply to any other situation. Worth pointing this out, context and specific use case is important.

Comment: @DaveHaigh Navigation is important here. In this case you could group the buttons in a download "area" that was clearly labeled "downloads", and it would then of course make sense to put the format on the button. Alternatively you could make a single download button and allow the user to select the format (better if there are a multitude of different formats).

Comment: I agree with Franchesca, buttons are meant to be actionable elements therefore they should specify the action. This case is a bit tricky since you want to specify the specific type of a possible set of similar options so that is where a button like Daan shows comes in. Either way both details should be supplied but for the most part if you go to a page to download something youre going to look for the big "Download" button not the big "PDF" button.

Comment: @DasBeasto Completely agree with this, it's why I liked to point out that having "Download" on it is fine, but the PDF icon in the button would  improve the user experience. While for a play button it doesn't matter which file it's going to play. You just want to hear music when clicking play. So the analogy wasn't just right for me and to me the answer isn't true, but I think opinions differ, and that's completely fine.